# c# can't load an icon

Tags: c#, windows, icons

How do I load an icon?

Here's the constructor of my app:

```
public MyApp()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   Icon icon = new Icon(@"/icons/tray.ico");
   // Icon is instance of 'System.Drawing.Icon'
}
```

When launched it just dies with this exception:

```
Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Locale.MyApp' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '9'.
```

Yes, the icon exists (at "/icons/tray.ico").
This error doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that if you comment out that specific line, the error goes away?

Comment: Do a try catch and throw the exception message.

Comment: @terrybozzio You should stick to drumming for Zappa  ;-) A forward slash is a valid path separator on Windows.